# Reprocess failed records in a bundle

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have use case where the end goal is to make a rest call with the transformed data in the apache beam program. If a record in a bundle fails due to connection or read timed out error, how can i reprocess only the failed records rather than processing the entire bundle containing that record.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple outputs for a single transform. So, for your case, you can output the failed records into the dedicated `PCollection` of "dead letters" and process it separately. Please, see an example [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/design-your-pipeline/#a-single-transform-that-produces-multiple-outputs)

```java
final TupleTag<String> successElms = new TupleTag<String>(){};
final TupleTag<String> failedElms = new TupleTag<String>(){};

PCollectionTuple mixedCollection =
    dbRowCollection.apply(ParDo
        .of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
          @ProcessElement
          public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            RestResult res = runRestCall(c.element());
            if (res.success()) {
              // Emit to main output, which is the output for successful elements.
              c.output(c.element());
            } else {
              // Emit to output for failed elements
              c.output(failedElms, c.element());
            }
          }
        })
        .withOutputTags(successElms,
        // Specify the other outputs as a TupleTagList.
                        TupleTagList.of(failedElms)));

// Get subset of the output with failed elements.
mixedCollection.get(failedElms).apply(ProcessFailedElms.create());
```